# How to click on internal element in an HTML table calendar

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium web-driver 3.6.0 version + C#. I try to click on the calendar to select different dates. The calendar has a drop-down lists to select year and month. When I need to select year, I should click on arrow near the text of current year, and select from list other year. If my wanted year doesn't present in the list, I should be click on "-"(minus) or on "+"(plus) and the list rolls up/down and displays other years.

When I try to click on plus or on minus from the list, I received MSG: 
"element not visible"
I tried to search a lot about this problem, and even tried all the suggested ways, but I could not solve the problem.

I'll detail what I tried:
 **1.** basic:

```
BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]")).Click();
```

**Result:** element not visible.

**2.** Click twice on element:

```
BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]")).Click();
BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]")).Click();
```

**Result:** element not visible.

**3.** Maximize the browser window:

```
driverUser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

**Result:** element not visible

**4.** Click via java-script:

```
IWebElement minusButtonInCalendar = BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)BrowserFactory.DriverUser ).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();" , minusButtonInCalendar);
```

**Result:** Running does not end.

**5.** Scroll into view of the element and then click:

```
IWebElement minusButtonInCalendar = BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)BrowserFactory.DriverUser ).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);" , minusButtonInCalendar);
BrowserFactory.DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[2]")).Click();
```

**Result:** Running does not end

**6.** Move to element and then click via browser.actions():

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserFactory.DriverUser , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//tr[1]")));
new Actions(BrowserFactory.DriverUser).MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```

**Result:** Running does not end

***Note:*** when I tried recording this case in selenium IDE, it didn't record this action.

*The related HTML code is:*

```
<div id="selectYear" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 100001; top: 26px; left: 143px;">
  <table style="font-family:arial; font-size:11px; border-width:1; border-style:solid; border-color:#a0a0a0;" onmouseover="clearTimeout(timeoutID2)" onmouseout="clearTimeout(timeoutID2);timeoutID2=setTimeout(" popDownYear() ",100)" width="44" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFDD">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=" #FFCC99 "" onmouseout="clearInterval(intervalID1);this.style.backgroundColor=" "" style="cursor: pointer;" onmousedown="clearInterval(intervalID1);intervalID1=setInterval(" decYear() ",30)" onmouseup="clearInterval(intervalID1)" align="center">-</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: this calendar control belong to any specific javascript library?

Comment: hi, Srikant Sahu. I don't know this. How can I check it out?

Comment: Can i have access to the web page and check it?

Comment: Hi,  santhosh kumar. I think I will not be able to give you access to my work site for information security reasons.
Could you please explain to me how to check it myself?

Comment: Hi, Srikant Sahu. Can I find this information in the HTML or JS code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you keep trying to click the TR instead of the TD. I would try the XPath

```
//div[@id='selectYear']//td[.='-']
```

You may need to wait for the element to be visible/clickable also. You could add something like

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectYear']//td[.='-']")));
```

Comment: Hi, JeffC. Your first remark was correct.
I have indeed changed the ID and I no longer receive the message of the invisible element.
I also tried to wait until the element appeared or clicked, according to the example you sent me
But I still can not click the "-" check in the calendar.

Do you have any more ideas?
I want to emphasize again that when I recorded it in the selenium IDE tool, it did not record this action. Maybe it can give us an idea of what might arise from the problem?

Comment: Another note: In all the ways I tried to push, I can see the cursor standing at the "-", as in the picture above, but it does not click on it, and does not roll the list of years to earlier years